# What is inclusive counting?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Q) Proof for the number of integers from $k$ to $n$ inclusive is $n - k+1$, where $n$ is presumed larger than $k$, i.e. $n > k$.

Q)Underlying questions

- What is inclusive counting?

I searched the internet but could not find a resource or book that proves the formula $n - k + 1$.

Where do we get the $1$ in the formula for the number of integers from $n$ to $k$ inclusive?

Is there proof for this formula and what are the base assumptions?

For the formula to be true do we have to always begin our counting from $1$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you search for "fencepost error" you'll  find discussions on it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Brian.

One interesting observation is that I stumbled on this problem from a fence post error.
Although I found discussions about it describing the error and using the formula b-a+1, they didn't seem to provide any background on the assumptions for this formula to be true. 

Additionally, I could not find any proof of this formula.

Comment: The proof of this fact will depend on the precise formalization of the question, but it would likely have to be by induction.  Effectively, if $n=k$ then we have $1$ number, and for any $m\geq k$, there is one more number from $k$ to $m+1$ inclusive than there is between $k$ to $m$ inclusive.  That is, the inductive step ends up just being $$(m+1) - k + 1 = (m-k+1)+1$$

Comment: Are you assuming that $k \leq n$?  In that case, there are $k - 1$ numbers smaller than $k$, so there are $n - (k - 1) = n - k + 1$ from $k$ to $n$ inclusive.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Brian. I have made the problem statement more formal. Just to reiterate the problem,
Proof for the number of integers from k to n inclusive is n - k+1, where n is presumed larger than k, i.e. n > k

Comment: Thank you for your reply Taussig. I am assuming n > k.

Comment: Inclusive means including the endpoints. Here that would be $k$ and $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $k \leq n$, the number of integers from $k$ to $n$ inclusive means the number of integers in the list $\{k, k + 1, k + 2, \ldots, n\}$.  Since the largest integer in the list is $n$ and the largest integer not in the list is $k - 1$, the number of integers in the list is $n - (k - 1) = n - k + 1$.  Notice that no assumptions were necessary other than $k, n$ are integers with $k \leq n$.

Comment: Thank you very much Taussig.